# Electric wiring for new LED lights when missing ground wire

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, grounding, led

I am changing basement lights to new LEDs.

The old light fixtures turned on/off via pull string and only two wires (white/black). The new LEDs are the same with the addition of a ground wire.

My questions:

- Do the new LEDs need to be grounded?
- Should they be grounded?

Comment: What is your question regarding the dimmer switch?

Comment: Ground is only for your safety and is not needed for the circuit/lights to work.  Lights are relatively safe to people.  LEDs need to be able to be dimable  to work on a dimmer

Comment: Is your only question "Do I need to ground the LEDs"? If so, please [edit] to remove all the irrelevant bits about the smoke detectors.